# jquery trigger event when deleting in ACE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

I'm using Ace editor on my website (which has so far been great!). I need to capture every moment some text on the editor changes. I have given the editor the id of "Ace_javascript_editor". When I use:

```
$("#Ace_javascript_editor").on("input",function(){
  //code here
}
```

It fires whenever I add text to the editor, but NOT when I DELETE text in the editor. I haven't found an elegant solution to what seems like a simple problem. On "Keyup" and "keydown" don't work in Ace editor in my experience and from what I've read online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the input event from the editor instead of the one from the browser

```
var editor = ace.edit("#Ace_javascript_editor")
....
editor.on("input",function(){
  //code here
})
```